# Wait until a process comes back from sleep

Tags: shell, scripting, terminal

`script.sh` is run by `run.sh` *N* times in parallel. For *N=1*, the `script.sh` process is set to sleep 30-45 seconds before it actually starts.

How can I order ALL `script.sh` instances for *N>1* **not to start** until the first (*N=1*) `script.sh` comes back from sleeping? The processes cannot communicate directly between each other.

What I want to is tell the other processes that the first one is still sleeping and they have to wait, they will be already initialized, but they cannot execute their code.

The processes also are not able to communicate directly between each other

Comment: Do you mean `run.sh` forks *N* copies of `script.sh` in parallel? Because if it's sequential then the second (and subsequent) instances of `script.sh` won't start until the previous one has completed. Unless `script.sh` forks itself into the background, I suppose. Can you provide a (cut down) example of the code in `run.sh` that starts up `script.sh` please.

Comment: If you don't want subsquent `script.sh` processes to do anything until the first one initializes, why start them at all? There are numerous ways you could signal the parent process to continue from the child. You could `wait` in the parent and have the child fork when ready. You could `kill -STOP $$` from the parent and `kill -CONT $PPID` from the child. You could share a pipe, have the parent block reading, and the child send something on it when ready. You could grab a lock on a file, and release the lock when ready. The list goes on.

Comment: @roaima yes, parallel.
What I want to is tell the other processess that the first one is still sleeping and they have to wait, they will be already initialised, but they cannot execute their code. The processess also are not able to communicate directly between each other

Comment: Can you remove the sleep from `script.sh` and add at the beginning of `run.sh`?

Comment: Apart from the given answers, the leading script could create a simple file and the other scripts could use `inotifywait` to wait for a specific action.

Answer (score 1):

If you know N beforehand, you can use fifo as a semaphore.

```
mkfifo sem;
exec 3<>sem
rm -f sem
```

Then make each N>1 process read a byte from that `&3`.
Since those bytes won't initially be available, it'll put them to sleep as well.

Once N==1 is done sleeping, it can write a N bytes into &3, waking up each process that has been waiting on a byte from &3.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
mkfifo p
exec 3<>p
rm p 
main()(
    echo $FUNCNAME beg
    sleep 2  &>/dev/null
    printf '\n\n\n' >&3
    echo $FUNCNAME end
) 
worker()(
    echo $FUNCNAME$1 beg
    read -n 1 <&3
    echo $FUNCNAME$1 end
) 

main &
worker 1 &
worker 2 &
worker 3 &
wait
```

Output:

```
main beg
worker1 beg
worker2 beg
worker3 beg
main end
worker2 end
worker3 end
worker1 end
```

Another way to do this might be with signals.
If you can make sure your script is run as a terminal job with `$$` (parent shell pid) being the process group id of the corresponding process group, then you can make your workers sleep indefinitely (ideally with processes calling the `pause` function; or with `sleep $hugevalue` if you can't do the former) and before that, make them establish a handler e.g., for SIGUSR1. The main process first worker should ignore the signal.
The first worker can then singnal all other workers by `kill -SIGUSR1 -$$`, which will kill the indefinite sleepers, making the workers continue.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap ' ' SIGUSR1
main()(
    trap - SIGUSR1
    echo $FUNCNAME beg
    sleep 2  &>/dev/null
    echo $FUNCNAME end
    kill -s SIGUSR1 -$$
) 
worker()(
    trap ' ' SIGUSR1
    echo $FUNCNAME$1 beg
    sleep 10000000000 &>/dev/null 
    echo $FUNCNAME$1 end
) 

main &
worker 1 &
worker 2 &
worker 3 &
wait
```

Output:

```
main beg
worker2 beg
worker1 beg
worker3 beg
main end
User defined signal 1
worker1 end
User defined signal 1
worker3 end
User defined signal 1
[1]    31554 user-defined signal 1  ./scr1
```

(I don't know how to turn off the `"user-defined signal 1"` messages)

Comment: According to the man page `trap '' USR1` should ignore SIGUSR1. « _If arg is the null string the signal specified by each sigspec is ignored by the shell and by the commands it invokes._ » But you've done that (well, almost) so I'm not sure what else is left.

Comment: I have a space there, though. In any case, I'd recommend against using the signal-based example. It's more fragile than the FIFO solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a snippet of your code I can only guess that it might be something like this:

```
for k in $(seq $N)
do
    script.sh &
done
```

So, in order to wait for the first one to complete before firing off the others you could do something like this:

```
for k in $(seq $N)
do
    script.sh &
    [[ $k == 1 ]] && wait
done
```

If the script itself takes a significant period of time to run this won't resolve your requirement as written, but unless you can separate the sleep from the processing I don't believe it's going to be sanely possible to achieve your requirement and still satisfy your stated criteria.